# sshing into localhost on Mac (el capitan) ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh

Cannot ssh into localhost and feel like I've tried everything on stackoverflow already. I've been playing around with the ssh_config to try to fix my issues, but I still either get "Connection closed by remote host" or something like "Authentications that can continue: publickey. debug1: No more authentication methods to try" depending on my setup

Here is my what I am currently seeing:

```
 $ ssh -v localhost

OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8

debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/<user>/.ssh/config

debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *

debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *

debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.

debug1: Connection established.

debug1: identity file /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa type 1

debug1: identity file /Users/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type 5

debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type 2

debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type 6

debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 3

debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type 7

debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 4

debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type 8

debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9

ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

my current setup of etc/ssh/ssh_config is:

```
This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

 Host *
   SendEnv LANG LC_*

# Configuration options and default values (see ssh_config(5) for their meaning):
#
#   Host # (no default)
#   AddressFamily any
#   AskPassGUI yes # (Apple only)
#   BatchMode no
#   BindAddress # (no default)
#   ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   Cipher 3des
#   ClearAllForwardings no
#   Compression no
#   CompressionLevel 6
#   ConnectionAttempts 1
#   ConnectTimeout # (no default)
#   ControlMaster no
#   ControlPath  # (no default)
#   ControlPersist no
#   DynamicForward
#   EnableSSHKeysign no
#   EscapeChar ~
#   ExitOnForwardFailure no
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Timeout 1200
#   ForwardX11Trusted no
#   XauthLocation xauth # Default is to search $PATH.  It is recommended that a full path be provided.
#   GatewayPorts no
#   GlobalKnownHostsFile /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts,/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials yes
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
    GSSAPITrustDNS yes
#   HashKnownHosts no
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   HostKeyAlgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
#   HostKeyAlias # (no default)
#   HostName # (set by command at run-time)
#   IdentitiesOnly no
#   IdentityFile .ssh/id_rsa,.ssh/id_dsa
#   IPQoS lowdelay
#   KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
#   KbdInteractiveDevices # (no default)
#   KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
#   LocalCommand  # (no default)
#   LocalForward  # (no default)
#   LogLevel INFO
#   NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost no
#   NumberOfPasswordPrompts 3
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   PKCS11Provider # (no default)
#   Port 22
#   PreferredAuthentications gssapi-with-mic,hostbased,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password  # (set by ssh at run-time)
#   Protocol 2
#   ProxyCommand # (no default)
#   PubkeyAuthentication yes
#   RekeyLimit 0
#   RemoteForward # (no default)
#   RequestTTY auto
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   SendEnv # (no default)
#   ServerAliveCountMax 3
#   ServerAliveInterval 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   TCPKeepAlive yes
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   UsePrivilegedPort no
#   User # (set by command at run-time)
#   UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts,~/.ssh/known_hosts2
#   VerifyHostKeyDNS no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   XAuthLocationi xauth

# XAuthLocation added by XQuartz (http://www.xquartz.org)
Host *
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

My permissions look okay according to other stack overflow answers

```
    -rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    3953 Jun  4 21:23 ssh_config
    -rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    4219 Jun  4 21:32 ssh_config~
    -rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    1624 Jan 21 17:10 ssh_config~orig
    -rw-------   1 root  wheel     668 Feb 26 07:39 ssh_host_dsa_key
    -rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     590 Feb 26 07:39 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
    -rw-------   1 root  wheel     227 May 29 19:20 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
    -rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     162 May 29 19:20 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
    -rw-------   1 root  wheel     387 May 29 19:20 ssh_host_ed25519_key
    -rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel      82 May 29 19:20 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
    -rw-------   1 root  wheel     965 Feb 26 07:39 ssh_host_key
    -rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     630 Feb 26 07:39 ssh_host_key.pub
    -rw-------   1 root  wheel    1675 Feb 26 07:39 ssh_host_rsa_key
    -rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel     382 Feb 26 07:39 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
    -rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    4216 Jun  4 21:11 sshd_config
    -rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    4215 Jun  4 21:02 sshd_config~
```

Not sure where else I could have gone wrong-- Any advice that you could suggest would be amazingly appreciated!!

EDIT: I am now getting

```
<pre>4 22:30:56 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.EEE1E6DD-C42C-45AD-9D7E-8D5C85D4E6C8[1032]): Service exited with abnormal code: 255
```

Jun  4 22:31:03 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.openbsd.ssh-agent[1067]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Jun  4 22:31:03 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.openbsd.ssh-agent): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Jun  4 22:31:13 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.openbsd.ssh-agent[1091]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Jun  4 22:31:13 MacBook-Pro com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.openbsd.ssh-agent): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.

my key seems to work when sshing but hangs at the line debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

if i unset $SSH_AUTH_SOCK before attempting to ssh, everything works as expected

Answer (score 0):

There should be a file called "authorized_keys". You should add (copy-paste the content) one of your own public key (the cert files) into it.

Comment: Still getting the same thing : (

Comment: Check permissions on the authorized_keys file too. I don't see it here.

Comment: -rwx------    1 user  owner        3136 Jun  4 21:08 authorized_keys

Comment: Usually there should be no execute permissions on that file. Try running `sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

To help others: there are multiple ssh config files! i must have gone over my ssh config a million times, but i was looking at the wrong file the entire time. my sshd_config had an error in it. since i was sshing into my own machine, both these files had to be set up correctly.  (one file for client, one for server configs--> at least that is my current understanding). cat /var/log/system.log | grep ssh pointed out that the error was in the other file. still hanging for me on ssh, but at least one step further : )